# Change class of an anchor when scroll is on a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

I am making a webpage which has anchor button on the top linking to different divs on the webpage, I want to change the background color of the button when the scroll is on that div and keep that color until it reaches the subsequent section.How can i use toggleClass in this ?

Comment: use scrollspy .

Comment: @kittyCat it requires the position to be relative

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The active link has green background.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var oneH = $('#one').offset().top; 
  var twoH = $('#two').offset().top; 

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= oneH){
    $("header a").removeClass("active");
    $("header a#aone").addClass("active");
  }

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= twoH){
    $("header a").removeClass("active");
    $("header a#atwo").addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.sect{
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
#two{
  background-color:blue;
}
header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
header a{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:red;
}
header a.active{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a id="aone" class="active">div1</a>
  <a id="atwo">div2</a>
</header>
<div class="sect" id="one"></div>
<div class="sect" id="two"></div>
```